# Handling excessive path separators

Tags: c, linux, unix, path, posix

I was wondering about issues related to path components concatenation, having in mind the particular case where a path ends up being invalid due to an excessive slash (like in `"foo//bar"`) introduced by improper concatenation.

But I then noticed a strange behaviour on Linux. See the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[4];
    FILE *f = fopen("/tmp/bar", "w");
    fwrite("bar", 1, 3, f);
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("/tmp////////bar", "r");
    if (f) {
        fread(buf, 1, 3, f);
        buf[3] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        fclose(f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above program actually prints `bar`, which means `"/tmp////////bar"` is implicitly reduced to `"/tmp/bar"`. Now, is this standard behaviour and can I rely on it, or should I still check explicitly path components to ensure they are well-formed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Standard (POSIX, 2004):

> 3.266 Pathname
>
> A character string that is used to identify a file. In the context of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, a pathname consists of, at most, {PATH_MAX} bytes, including the terminating null byte. It has an optional beginning slash, followed by zero or more filenames separated by slashes. A pathname may optionally contain one or more trailing slashes. Multiple successive slashes are considered to be the same as one slash.

The 2013 revision has similar wording, but makes the exact pathname `//` (two slashes, nothing else) implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of [Jens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22203091/841108):

On Linux, [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) describes the procedure used inside the kernel to interpret file path.

And you could use [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) to "canonicalize" some path in *C* (it should "remove" most or all [symlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html)-s...). See also [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) and [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) which could be helpful to handle shell-friendly paths (e.g. expand `~/` or `$HOME/` and e.g. `a*.c` ....).